# When i install phpfox site it shows me an annoying language looks encoding error

Tags: php, linux, phpfox

I have installed phpfox on my linux based server cnektdev.com but when i installed it showing me a strange error.

However the same code i run on 2 different servers working fine
cnekt.com
techchef.org/cnekt

but when i talked with my hosting guys rosehosting they checked and say it looks your hosting is fine.

I reinstalled default phpfox here then, but found no such good luck.

& when i check requirement of phpfox on my server it shows its fine,
http://cnektdev.com/phpfox-requirement-check-master/phpfox.php
for reference i have pasted the screenshot of test
http://s28.postimg.org/tgjv1z7st/phfox.png

but when its installed it shows me an strange language.

Please some body help me to give me a hint how can i resolve this issue and why this issue comes?

Comment: a guy have a good experience on phpfox responded me that check gzip on your server.. i am taking a look in to that.

Comment: but i found its enable and found no good luck, can any guy please help

Comment: This is the encoding details from the server:

php -i | grep encoding
zend.script_encoding => no value => no value
iconv.input_encoding => ISO-8859-1 => ISO-8859-1
iconv.internal_encoding => ISO-8859-1 => ISO-8859-1
iconv.output_encoding => ISO-8859-1 => ISO-8859-1
HTTP input encoding translation => disabled
mbstring.encoding_translation => Off => Off
mbstring.internal_encoding => no value => no value

Answer (score 0):

i solved it:)
it was GZIP error solved it by turning of ZLIB as guided by my friend:)